# reactjs - correct way to update data in sibling components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-context, react-component

I'll mention in advanced that this is not a technical question on how to do the data update between 2 sibling components, rather what is the correct way to do so.

I have the following component tree structure:

```
App
|
-- Home
   |
   -- SearchBar
   |  |
   |  -- Filters
   |
   -- ItemsList
```

`ItemsList` has logic in it to load the list of items from an API call and show the list of items on the page. It also manages the state of the articles. If an article is deleted it removes it from the list and updates it's state.

`SearchBar` is a component that contains a textual search that is displayed above the list where a user can enter text to search and also has a button that opens the `Filters` component where the user can filter different parameters. Once the user search's or filters the list in the `ItemsList` component should be updated accordingly.

There are a few ways I can think to achieve this:

1. Using react context - The provider will be on the `Home` component (or another component for holding `SearchBar` and `ItemsList` - and both `SearchBar` and `ItemsList` will contain a consumer that will updated the state with a method in the provider - those updating the components. This in my opinion create some dependency between those components and they are not really standing on their own (the `ItemsList` component should be used in other pages as well - of course this is still possible, but yet does not feel so "clean").
2. The `ItemsList` component will contain public methods such as "delete item", and "clear list" and those methods will be called from the home component. The `SearchBar` will get a property with a function as an event - something like "onFilterChanged" and will call the method on `ItemsList` (I will need to hold a ref to that component). But working like that feels like each component can stand and be re-used on it's own merit - but loosing the "reactiveness" and more wire up that needs to be done.

Are there any other ways to achieve what I'm looking for that I'm not thinking of?
What is the correct way to architect this kind of solutions?

Answer (score 1):

When two siblings need access to the same state, keeping the state in a mutual parent component is a common and recommended way of handling it (the official [React documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html#step-4-identify-where-your-state-should-live) encourages that approach for most cases). That way, both the state and any methods to update the state can be passed to both children as needed, and any updates made by one child will be reflected in the other child.

There can be drawbacks to that approach: Depending on the size of the application, [prop drilling](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/what-is-prop-drilling-and-how-to-avoid-it/) can make code confusing and difficult to maintain—especially if one component that is using said data is being used in multiple places, deeply nested, or both.

For such occasions, holding the state in context or redux is a more appropriate approach. The first option that you listed is completely legitimate and what I would recommend. Maybe extracting your context entirely (not keeping it in your `Home` component and instead creating the context in its own file) would help things feel more "clean."

Determining when to use which approach is something that comes with time and experience. When choosing an approach, it is helpful to keep your future plans in mind. If you know the application will be small and simple, keeping the state in a parent component is a great move. If you have big plans for your application, using context or Redux from the start will be easiest.

Thankfully, the worst case scenario is that you decide to change from one approach to the other, which can always be done (confusing and tedious as it may be at times).

Comment: Thanks for the elaborated answer. I do plan ahead and this is why I have asked what is the correct approach - the `ItemsList` component as I mentioned is planned to be used on different pages, but not necessarily with the `SearchBar` component - this is why `ItemsList` holds it's own state.